# How to override a mock for an individual test within a class that already has a mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a test class that has a mock decorator, and several tests. Each test receives the mock, because mock is defined on the class level. Great. Here's what it looks like:

```
@mock.patch("foo", bar)
class TestMyThing(TestCase):
  def test_A(self):
    assert something

  def test_B(self):
    assert something

  def test_C(self):
    assert something

  def test_D(self):
    assert something
```

I now want `test_D` to get a have a different value mocked for `foo`. I first try:

```
@mock.patch("foo", bar)
class TestMyThing(TestCase):
  def test_A(self):
    assert something

  def test_B(self):
    assert something

  def test_C(self):
    assert something

  @mock.patch("foo", baz)
  def test_D(self):
    assert something
```

This doesn't work. Currently to get unittest to take the `mock.patch` that decorates `test_D`, I have to remove the `mock.patch` that decorates the **class**. This means creating lots of DRY and doing the following:

```
class TestMyThing(TestCase):
  @mock.patch("foo", bar)
  def test_A(self):
    assert something

  @mock.patch("foo", bar)
  def test_B(self):
    assert something

  @mock.patch("foo", bar)
  def test_C(self):
    assert something

  @mock.patch("foo", baz)
  def test_D(self):
    assert something
```

This is non ideal due to DRY boilerplate, which makes it error prone and violates open-closed principle. Is there a better way to achieve the same logic?

Comment: What violation of the open/closed principle do you see with your solution? At the very least, you don't have to call `mock.patch` multiple times. `x = mock.patch("foo", bar)`, then `@x def test_A(self) ...`, etc.

Comment: @chepner that is a really nice syntactic treat, thanks! As for why this solution (even with nice syntax) violates I/O is because in order to bend the rules for an individual test (be open for extension), it's necessary to revisit old tests and edit them. (not being closed for modification). Maybe I am being overly theoretical connecting the dots to the design principle... but at the very least I want to be able to have a default behaviour for all tests, and then break that behaviour for one test at a go. The accepted answer covers this, if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! You can leverage the [`setUp`/`tearDown`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) methods of the `unittest.TestCase` and the fact that [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) in its "pure" form (i.e. not as context manager or decorator) returns a "patcher" object that has [`start`/`stop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop) methods to control when exactly it should do its magic.

You can call on the patcher to start inside `setUp` and to stop inside `tearDown` and if you keep a reference to it in an attribute of your test case, you can easily stop it manually in selected test methods. Here is a full working example:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch


class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def bar() -> int:
        return 1


class TestMyThing(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.foo_bar_patcher = patch.object(Foo, "bar", return_value=42)
        self.mock_foo_bar = self.foo_bar_patcher.start()
        super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.foo_bar_patcher.stop()
        super().tearDown()

    def test_a(self):
        self.assertEqual(42, Foo.bar())

    def test_b(self):
        self.assertEqual(42, Foo.bar())

    def test_c(self):
        self.assertEqual(42, Foo.bar())

    def test_d(self):
        self.foo_bar_patcher.stop()
        self.assertEqual(1, Foo.bar())
```

This patching behavior is the same, regardless of the different variations like `patch.object` (which I used here), `patch.multiple` etc.

Note that for this example it is not necessary to keep a reference to the actual `MagicMock` instance generated by the patcher in an attribute, like I did with `mock_foo_bar`. I just usually do that because I often want to check something against the mock instance in my test methods.

It is worth mentioning that you *can* also use `setUpClass`/`tearDownClass` for this, but then you need to be careful with re-starting the patch, if you stop it because those methods are (as the name implies) only called once for each test case, whereas `setUp`/`tearDown` are called once before/after *each test method*.

**PS**: The default implementations of `setUp`/`tearDown` on `TestCase` do nothing, but it is still good practice IMO to make a habit of calling the superclass' method, unless you deliberately want to omit that call.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent and really detailed answer. This is the exact type of solution I was looking for: a rule that applies to the entire test class, but which can be broken for individual tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While accepted answer is perfectly fine, I'd go for approach which keeps decorator for the class and uses context managers for methods in which you want to override a mock, see sample code below:

```
@mock.patch("foo", bar)
class TestMyThing(TestCase):
  def test_A(self):
    assert something

  def test_B(self):
    assert something

  def test_C(self):
    assert something

  def test_D(self):
    with patch('foo', baz):
        assert something
```

This achieves your goal, as context manager mock is applied inside of a test function, so it happens after applying the class decorator mock and therefore it effectively overrides class decorator mock. Also, I think it's simpler and it requires less code, especially if you have no other reason to implement `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods.